# Selected row in JTable is not highlighting

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablerowsorter

Well, this is my first post here.  But I am little frustrated because I have search everywhere but nothing is working.  I have `JTable` and code works as expected below lines right after if (`value.equals("CMAU1294522")`) .. however only  one cell is show square box. I mouse clicked on a particular row, I want the entire row to show light gray (I think that is standard).

```
table = new JTable(sorter)  {  
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
        Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
        Object value = getModel().getValueAt(row, col);


        UIManager.put("Table.editRow", new javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource(Color.YELLOW)); 


      if(editingRow ==1){
          table.setSelectionBackground(Color.red);
        }
        if (getSelectedRow() == row) {
            table.setSelectionBackground(Color.red);
        }
        if (value.equals("CMAU1294522")) {
            comp.setBackground(Color.red);
        } else if (value.equals("PNCT")) {
            comp.setBackground(Color.green);
        } else if (NewJApplet.contReady.containsKey(value)) {
            comp.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        } else if (NewJApplet.badCont.containsKey(value)) {
            comp.setBackground(Color.red);
        } else {
            comp.setBackground(Color.white);
        }
        return comp;
    }
```

Is there any way to do it in `prepareRenderer` function I already have?

Answer (score 1):

> I there any way to do it in PreparRenerere function I already have?

You code to get the "value" is wrong. You always get the value of the current cell being rendered. If you want to highlight the entire row based on a specific value then you need to hardcode the column:

```
Object value = getModel().getValueAt(row, ???);
```

Also, it looks like you are sorting the data in the table so you should be using getValueAt(...) instead of getModel().getValueAt(), so you check the data in the sort table, not the data in the unsorted model.

Check out the example code in [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for a working example.

Comment: Thanks .  But it finally worked.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @HiTech, glad it helped, Don't forget to "accept" the answer, by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.